# how to open local html file with MS edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, local-files

I have local html files that my program produce.
How can i open these local html files from command line with MS Edge?

For MS InterbetExplorer I have (working) command like (`%f` is path to html):

```
{pathToExplorerExecutable}"file:///%f"
```

For MS Edge I found executable in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, but when I try same command, that I use for IE, nothing happens.

I also tried command: `start microsoft-edge:file///%f` still did not work.

Is there any way to open local file in MS Edge from command line?

Answer (score 2):

In case of Edge Browser it is:

```
start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge file:///C:/test.html
```

#### Where is that `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge` value from?

That value is in format `[PackageFamilyName]![ApplicationID]`.
It can be found in the AppManifest.xml of Edge browser or via regitry (if Edge is set as the default webbrowser):

1. Get default webbrowser from the `ProgId` value of registry key:
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice`
   The value will be `AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9` in case of Edge.
2. Take that `ProgId` value to open the following key:
   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[ProgId]\Application`
   or
   `HKEY_USERS\[CurrentUserID]_Classes\[ProgId]\Application`
   So in case of Edge, open `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9\Application`.
3. Read the value of `AppUserModelID`.